# SQL as keyword is not recognized

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm editing a stored procedure to get the distance and the sort it from that. The query I'm using is working on another stored procedure.

```
    SELECT  *,


( 
    ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 41.993000000  ) ) 
          * COS( RADIANS( u.real_users_lat ) )
          * COS( RADIANS( u.real_users_long ) - RADIANS( -87.696207000 ) )
          + SIN( RADIANS( 41.993000000  ) )
          * SIN( RADIANS( u.real_users_lat ) )
      )
    * 6371
    ) AS distance_in_km

FROM products
LEFT JOIN users u on u.id = products.created_by
LEFT JOIN product_categories on product_categories.product_id = products.id
WHERE products.starting_bid <= @price and product_categories.category_id = @category_id
ORDER BY 
     CASE WHEN @sort_direction = 'asc' THEN products.date_created END asc,
     CASE WHEN @sort_direction = 'desc' THEN products.date_created END desc,
    CASE WHEN @sort_distance = 'nearest' THEN distance_in_km END desc,
    CASE WHEN @sort_distance = 'farthest' THEN distance_in_km END asc

END
```

The error is `Invalid column name 'distance_in_km'.` but on my other stored procedure here it is working.

```
SELECT 
    distinct Products.*, 
    (
        SELECT Count(bids.id) 
        FROM bids
        Where bids.product_id = products.id
    ) as bid_count ,
    (
    SELECT firebase_user_id
    FROM Users
    Where Users.id = created_by
    ) as seller_firebase_id , 
    ( 
    ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 41.993000000  ) ) 
          * COS( RADIANS( u.real_users_lat ) )
          * COS( RADIANS( u.real_users_long ) - RADIANS( -87.696207000 ) )
          + SIN( RADIANS( 41.993000000  ) )
          * SIN( RADIANS( u.real_users_lat ) )
      )
    * 6371
    ) AS distance_in_km


FROM Products
LEFT JOIN areas on areas.id = products.area
LEFT JOIN Product_categories on Product_categories.product_id = products.id
LEFT JOIN Users u on u.id = Products.created_by 
WHERE products.status <> 4 
ORDER BY distance_in_km DESC


END
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don't think we are going to be able to reproduce your problem, as I see nothing wrong with your first query.  Give us a reproducible example please.

Comment: Any reason you're not using the geography datatype that's been built into SQL Server since 2008, rather than implementing geography calculations by hand?

Comment: Hi Damien, when I was trying to find a geography solution for getting the nearest and farthest locations this is what I found on stack overflow and basically I heard that the geography database value were hard to use.

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong. SQL server simply does not allow the aliased column to be used in that way.  A straight `WHERE` is ok, but you cannot use them in expressions.

Don't ask me why!

If you need to do this then wrap your SELECT statement in a CTE or inline view and it will work fine.

There's also an extra `END` at the end; perhaps that's just a copy-and-paste problem with the question, though.

This should be close using an inline view

```
SELECT  *,distance_in_km
FROM products
LEFT JOIN 
(select *, ( 
    ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 41.993000000  ) ) 
          * COS( RADIANS( u.real_users_lat ) )
          * COS( RADIANS( u.real_users_long ) - RADIANS( -87.696207000 ) )
          + SIN( RADIANS( 41.993000000  ) )
          * SIN( RADIANS( u.real_users_lat ) )
      )
    * 6371
    ) AS distance_in_km
from users) u on u.id = products.created_by
LEFT JOIN product_categories on product_categories.product_id = products.id
WHERE products.starting_bid <= @price and product_categories.category_id = @category_id
ORDER BY 
     CASE WHEN @sort_direction = 'asc' THEN products.date_created END asc,
     CASE WHEN @sort_direction = 'desc' THEN products.date_created END desc,
    CASE WHEN @sort_distance = 'nearest' THEN distance_in_km END desc,
    CASE WHEN @sort_distance = 'farthest' THEN distance_in_km END asc
```

Eralper's answer Shows the CTE general technique.

Comment: but on the second query i'm using the distance_in_km as an order by property and it's working?

Comment: Yes it works on ORDER BY when used directly.  Your failing example is a complex expression. It's not allowed in the expression part, not the ORDER BY part.

Comment: @Jovin - I can confirm that `ORDER BY an_aliased_column` works but `ORDER BY CASE WHEN x < 20 then an_aliased_column END` does not work. So it's this and the extra `END`.

Comment: The complex expression is the start of the geo query correct?  What is the expression part? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The "complex expression" I refer to is the `CASE` for the `ORDER BY`. Sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah so I can't use it in an over complicated expression? but only on a simple one? How could I rework my function so it can still act as case when but still use the aliased column?

Comment: @Jovin - As LoztInSpace said, use a CTE to do that big calculation (then join on it).

Comment: @LoztInSpace thanks for the explanation! I get why it's not working now. But now how do I still get the sort value depending on the parameters that I receive if I cannot use CASE WHEN?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ahh I think I got it.. I'm curious as to what the extra END you are talking about though. If I remove the last END my query doesn't work.

Comment: @Jovin - What's shown in the question has an extra `END` right at the end.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you mean here ?
    CASE WHEN sort_distance = 'farthest' THEN distance_in_km END asc

END

Comment: @Jovin - Yes, there.

Answer (score 0):

Jovin, you cannot use a computed column directly in the SQL it is created

I mean, following will not work

```
declare @sort varchar(5) = 'desc'
select [name], trim([name]) as tname
from sys.tables
order by 
    case when @sort = 'desc' then tname end desc,
    case when @sort = 'asc' then tname end asc
```

You can do one of the following

```
declare @sort varchar(5) = 'desc'
select [name], trim([name]) as tname
from sys.tables
order by 
    case when @sort = 'desc' then trim([name]) end desc,
    case when @sort = 'asc' then trim([name]) end asc
```

Or just use [SQL CTE](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-multiple-cte-syntax-sql-cte-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) expression

```
declare @sort varchar(5) = 'desc'
;with cte as (
    select [name], trim([name]) as tname
    from sys.tables
) 
select *
from cte
order by 
    case when @sort = 'desc' then tname end desc,
    case when @sort = 'asc' then tname end asc
```

Comment: Wait so I have put the entire function after the then keyword in the order by function? Why is the second one working in terms of it being able to sort when I basically did the same thing as the first one? Thanks for your help Eralper.

Comment: You *can* use an alias in Standard SQL in ORDER BY because it's logically processed *after* the Select list is created (It's just strange that SQL Server doesn't allow using it in a CASE)

Comment: I actually prefer to use CTE in such cases, because the result is calculated and stored somehow in memory or in a temp table, then sorting by using the CTE column name is much more clear and avoid code repeating in different parts of the SQL script